# What is meaning of "Still." as a sentence in conversation?

Tags: meaning, australian-english

I'm reading an Australian novel. 
There are an expression "Still." but I don't know the exact meaning.

like

She nodded and smiled. "Still. What can I do?"

or

"Still. It's a real shame."

What is the meaning of "Still." in conversations? Is it slang?

Comment: I don't think this is specifically Australian usage.  [The meaning of *still* here is "regardless" or "despite that"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/still); the speaker is saying "*Despite what has just been said, what can I do?" or "Regardless of that, it is a real shame."  (I realize that this is difficult because *still* has so many different meanings.)

Comment: I see it in other regional variations of English.  I consider it to be a verbal shrug.  "Yes, that may be true, but what of it/what can I do/what do you expect?"

Answer (score 1):

In your examples

> still

has the meaning

> given the *(current)* situation
>   eventhough
>
> Still. What can I do?
>   *given the current situation, what can I do?*
>
> Still. It's a real shame.
>   *given the situation, it's a real shame.*